# Remove files added in lots of commits in the past

Tags: git, github

In the last 30-40 commits I included a folder and I just realized I shouldn't have done that.

My main concern is that when I push those changes to Github, it will take a while because of the size of those files...

**Is there a way to completely remove that folder (or some files) from past commits?**

Comment: You didnt push it yet did you ?

Comment: I guess someone beat me to the answer :)

Comment: Also, you might want to remove the 'cvs' tag for this post, it's not really related to CVS at all.

Comment: If you are concerned about space you should execute the clean up and compressing commands in the github tutorial too.

Comment: @Learath2 Could you point me to that part of the tutorial?

Comment: ın [this](http://help.github.com/remove-sensitive-data/) link there is Cleanup part just after the filter-branch operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most probably want to use `git filter-branch`. Github has a fairly good tutorial how to use it [here](http://help.github.com/remove-sensitive-data/).

The following line should do the trick:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch -r <path>' --prune-empty -- --all
```

Make sure you're using `-r <path>` if you want to remove a folder.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will take a look at it now and I'll let you know how it went!

Comment: Got it. I edited your question to include exactly what I ran, so that users don't necessarily have to go to Github to find the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can edit history in Git by doing an interactive rebase.  Figure out the first commit before you introduced the folder and `git rebase -i <that commit id>`.

Comment: If the folder has changed in many of the commits, it'll be a pretty tedious process with interactive rebase. To remove files from a complete history, filter-branch is a better choice (imo)

Comment: I have used `git rebase -i` to change name of commits, merge commits... but how exactly does it help me in this context?

Comment: @OscarMederos You can also edit commits (change 'pick' to 'edit) to remove the folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use git filter branch `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch YOURFOLDER' --prune-empty -- --all` this command will run through all the commits deleting YOURFOLDER you can push normally as you didn't push it yet. I use this command quite alot.